# Help removing a failed replica from a FreeIPA setup

Tags: ldap, replication, freeipa

I have two FreeIPA servers in my system; ns-1 and ns-2.  To my limited knowledge, ns-1 is our main ipa server and ns-2 was setup as a replica.  But I may be incorrect in that regard.

In my attempts to upgrade the OS on ns-2, the upgrade failed somewhere in the middle and now the machine is toast.  ns-1 is still operating fine as I was holding off on upgrading that machine until ns-2 was complete.

I blew away ns-2 and rebuilt a new VM in its place and now want to set it up as the new ns-2 replacement.  The problem though is that ns-1 still has a record of the original ns-2 and is preventing the ipa-replica-install command from succeeding on my new ns-2.

In ns-1's Web UI, it still lists ns-2 as an ipa server and displays ns-2 in the topology graph.

From the ns-1 machine I've issued the following commands:

```
# ipa-replica-manage list
ns-2.<mydomain>.<com>: master
ns-1.<mydomain>.<com>: master

# ipa-replica-manage del --force --cleanup ns-2.<mydomain>.<com>
Updating DNS system records
Not allowed on non-leaf entry

# ldap_delete -x -h 127.0.0.1 -D 'cn=directory manager' -w <my password> 'cn=ns-2.<mydomain>.<com>,cn=masters,cn=ipa,cn=etc,dc=<mydomain>.<com>'
ldap_delete: Operation not allowed on non-leaf (66)
      additional info: Entry has replication conflicts as children

# ipa-replica-manage dnsrange-show
ns-2.<mydomain>.<com>: Connection failed: cannot connect to 'ldaps://ns-2.<mydomain>.<com>:636': Transport endpoint is not connected
```

On my new ns-2 machine I've run the ip-client-install command successfully.  And then I ran the "ipa-replica-install --setup-dns --setup-ca --no-forwarders -P "  It fails because the ns-1 machine appears to believe that there's already an ns-2 machine defined.

I've found the following threads that appears to have experienced the same problem, but no resolution is included:
https://www.spinics.net/linux/fedora/fedora-users/msg498296.html

I've tried following this documentation, but it does not explain how to resolve replicas that have "children":
https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/identity_management_guide/ipa-replica-manage#repl-conflicts

Answer (score 0):

i had a similar issue and it took me a lot of time to figure it out. Just wanted to share my findings.

I could not a remove a single replica because the topology plugin i could not remove a non-leaf entry. But it was a simple leaf server.
After trying a lot of stuff, i found out, that some replication conflicts were the reason.

So removing those let me remove the faulty replica.

Removing replication conflicts is explained here: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/de-de/red_hat_directory_server/11/html/administration_guide/managing_replication-solving_common_replication_conflicts